# AMPL: Linking Master and Sub Model Files in Stochastic Programming

Tags: ampl

I am trying to implement a two course stochastic programming based on Stefano Nasini's "Benders’ decomposition with AMPL", available [here](http://www-eio.upc.es/~nasini/Blog/Benders%20decomposition_AMPL.pdf). There are two model files that are specified in the examples of tutorial - one representing the master-problem and the other representing the sub-problem. In the run file which is used to implement the decomposition, how are the problem files declared or shown to the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model and data files that specify the components of the master problem and the subproblem are included in the run file with the model and data commands:

```
model trnloc1d.mod;
data trnloc1.dat;
```

and then corresponding named problems are declared:

```
problem Master: x, z, Total_Cost, Cut_Defn;
problem Sub: lambda, mu, Dual_Ship_Cost, Dual_Ship;
```

Note that there is not two but one model file that contains all the declarations for both problems although you can split it into two.

The problem names (`Sub` or `Master`) are used in the script that implements Benders decomposition when specifying which problem to solve, for example the following command solves the subproblem

```
solve Sub;
```